# Authentication method not supported: GET

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I'm using the below JSP code. When I'm calling `/login` in my URL to login it is opening the login page. But when I call the `/loginProcess` via URL it is showing the following error:

> error:Authentication method not supported: GET

Please help me where I am getting wrong.

My JSP-code:

```
<form:form modelAttribute="user" method="POST" name="loginForm" action="loginProcess" id="loginForm">
    <input type="hidden" name="<csrf:token-name/>" value="<csrf:token-value uri="/loginProcess"/>"/>            
    <div id="login-container" class="fatpad ltMetal shadowBig round top">
        <spring:bind path="userName">
            <c:if test="${status.error}">
                <div id="formError" class="errortip shinyRed round shadowBig thinpad"><span><form:errors path="userName" /></span>
                </div>
            </c:if>
        </spring:bind>
        <fieldset>
            <ul id="login-form">
                <li>
                    <label for="j_username"><spring:message code="login.UserName" /></label>
                    <input id="j_username" name="j_username" type="text" class="required" placeholder="Email Address" maxlength="40" <spring:bind path="userName"> <c:if test="${not empty status.error}"> value='<%= (session.getAttribute(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_USERNAME_KEY) == null ? userName :session.getAttribute(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_USERNAME_KEY)) %>'</c:if> </spring:bind> />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="j_password"><spring:message code="login.Password" /></label>
                    <input id="j_password" name="j_password" type="password" class="required" placeholder="Password" maxlength="30"/>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="buContainer">
                        <a class="buOrange large" id="submit" href="#" onclick="validateForm()"><spring:message code="login.logIn" /></a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </fieldset>
        <div class="buContainer">
            <a id="forgot-link" href="forgotPassword?<csrf:token-name/>=<csrf:token-value uri="/forgotPassword"/>"><spring:message code="login.forgotPassword" /></a>   
        </div>              
    </div>
</form:form>
```

Comment: A controller mapped to `/loginProcess` probably implements only method to cover `POST` requests. Anyway, how could you process your login without providing anything like user name or password

Answer (score 1):

/loginProcess is not GET its a POST action and you are trying to access it using GET

Answer (score 0):

change form method type to GET.like method="GET",
you define form method is post and access get request so this error is occur